# c# open a specific pdf page with getting data from sql

Tags: c#, sql, pdf

In my project I want to open a specific pdf page. I found a code from stackoverflow which works great here is the code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page=3\" \"C:\\Users\\test.pdf";
    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

Yet this code is working perfectly in c# when i want to get `startInfo.Arguments's` data from sql it only opens the last page which I opened with `button1_Click`.

This is how im trying to get data with sql;

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From table ", baglanti);
baglanti.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
try
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader[1].ToString() == "pdf")
        {
            startInfo.FileName = @reader[4].ToString();
            startInfo.Arguments = reader[3].ToString();
            Process.Start(startInfo);
        }           
    }

    baglanti.Close();
    reader.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

Another thing is after I open a specific pdf page something like page 15 with button and then I want to open pdf from windows normally it also opens from page 15. Its like I cant dispose the argument after I use it.

So is anyone know anything about this issue or can see where  I am wrong?

Comment: What is the output of your reader when you debug it? Set a breakpoint and go step by step through the code and see what output you get.

Comment: reader[4] is C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe

reader[3] is "/A \"page=1\" \"C:\\Users\\dzcgkv\\Desktop\\Kiosk\\EOP-HPV_006_DHPV_HİDROLİK_MONTAJ.pdf"

yet it still opens page 3 cause of button1_click

Comment: If you move the sql code to button click event, it opens on page 3 or on last page? Notice that you're missing `\"` at the end of your arguments. Your string looks like `\"C:\\Users.......MONTAJ.pdf`. After `.pdf` you're missing `\"`. Like `.pdf\"`.

Comment: reader[3] is /A \"page=1\" \"C:\\Users\\dzcgkv\\Desktop\\Kiosk\\EOP-HPV_006_DHPV_HİDROLİK_MONTAJ.pdf\"

thats the right one. I added last \ myself at my table otherwise program cant find the document. Thats the only difference between button_1Click's argument and the data im getting from sql for the argument

Comment: Make sure in your sql table entries has no escape sequences. If you add an entry to your table e.g. `\"page=2\"` it will automatically add two more backslashes to it. So it would be `\\"page=2\\"`. I just created a test application with your code and added some value to the DB. It worked fine. Make sure your row entries are correct (check it with e.g. MSSQL Management Studio or any other DB application). Or simply check the results using a `MessageBox`. For example `MessageBox.Show(reader[3].ToString()`.

Comment: I did what you asked and what I catch is after I set a breakpoint, on argument step i get  /A \"page=1\" \"C:\\Users\\dzcgkv\\Desktop\\Kiosk\\EOP-HPV_006_DHPV_HİDROLİK_MONTAJ.pdf\" from text visiualizer which is what it should be( I just copied and pasted here from visiualizer) but when I paste it on c# it became like this / A \"page=1\" \"C:\\Users\\dzcgkv\\Desktop\\Kiosk\\EOP-HPV_006_DHPV_HİDROLİK_MONTAJ.pdf\" there is a space between / and A . Do you think it is something related with my problem?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that. Yes, remove this space, it should work. Your code works fine in my application

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine when I use it in a test application. What I noticed now from your comments is that you have a space in the arguments between `/` and `A`. Remove it and make sure your path to the PDF is correct (no double escape sequences in your database row or something similar). So your output should be the following to get it running properly:

```
reader[1]: "pdf"
reader[3]:  "/A \"page=1\" \"C:\\Users\\dzcgkv\\Desktop\\Kiosk\\EOP-HPV_006_DHPV_HİDROLİK_MONTAJ.pdf\""
reader[4]: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Foxit Software\\Foxit Reader\\FoxitReader.exe"
```